# Java architecture for updating then comparing differences

Tags: java, database, performance, architecture

I currently have an application that maintains the latest information for a transaction in an object stored into a database.  Due to the high performance and concurrency we are currently hitting a bottleneck with garbage collections.  Right now new data comes in as a fresh object that is then updated with the old information from the database and run through several more look processes to ensure the most up to date information is available.  That new updated object is stored back into the database and then the two objects are compared for differences before notifying downstream systems.

I would like to remove the concept of two separate objects that are compared because the object is very large with many nested structures and is creating a large amount of garabage collections.  Is there a way to update a single object, but be able to see what has changed on that object ideally without reflection and annotations to maintain performance?

```
NewObject
    Timestamp: 456
    Name: joe
    Event: breakfast

OldObject
    Timestamp: 123
    Name: joe
    Event: dinner
```

Save new Object to database then compare

```
if(OldObject.getTimestamp().isNewerThan(NewObject.getTimestamp()) 
&&       NewObject.getEvent() == "breakfast") {
    NotifyHandler.notify(NewObject.getName() + " at Breakfast");
}
```

Comment: Do you need to know what has changed?  Or just the fact that the object has changed?

Comment: Why are you comparing objects is beyond me, but if you are going to compare two large objects and you know one of them is already modified, then hashCode() is useless. For high number of requests, you can use Redis and insert the object directly in Redis(not memcached).

Comment: I need to know what change and how it has changed.  For instance if both objects have a timestamp I would need to know that it has changed and what the two values are.  I would only need the old values for fields that have changed.

Comment: Can you give an example in (pseudo) code what you have and would like to have? Tracking changes in an object could be as simple as setting a boolean from every setter.

Comment: Why? You retrieve an object from DB, update specific fields and edit the already existing objects in DB, that's it, no comparison required. You should start by changing your approach of your edit guy, is what I think, and I told you about Redis already.

Comment: Also : Without posting relevant code, no one can help you. Downvoting. You can refer how to ask a question by checking http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and how to create an example by reading this : http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @We are Borg After updating the database fields I need to be able to do see the changes that occurred to trigger off business rules to send data downstream for people who need certain changes.

Comment: Ok, I can help you in your comparator logic, but if you want better concurrency control, then its Redis which you have to use. Secondly, have you tried parallel Garbage collection with multiple threads, I think that would work in your scenario. I can suggest some test values if you use Tomcat.

Comment: Currently this is a queue based application in a backend system.  We have been working on Tuning the IBM Java 7 JDK with relatively decent success.  The goal at this point would be to minimize garabage collection from an application level.  Our pattern is  similar to:  Get NewObject -> get OldDbObject -> merge OldObject into NewObject -> several lookups merging data into newObject -> Based off differences between two send data to downstream systems

Comment: My approach would be like this

    if(OldObject.getTimestamp().isNewerThan(NewObject.getTimestamp()) 

    // Override old object with new object.

In your example, you have only one attribute. Assume that there are 20+ attributes are present in a given object, it's better to update entire object instead of checking one by one attribute of given object.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to make some kind of change log, I would probably build it by creating setters on the original object that create the thing.

So, when the database update starts, reset the change log, then, as each method sets new values for the existing object, compare it against the old value (internally to the setter method), and if different, add an entry to your change log.

When done with the update, your change log should have all your updates.